# c# How to read the content of a website as text?

Tags: c#

How to get the content of a site?

The site im talking about is just a simple page that doesn't have any other links on it:

take this as example: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Queens.java.html

I just want to read the content and save it on a string so later on I can manipulate it easily.

Any idea? or tutorial?

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read the content of a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531106/how-to-read-the-content-of-a-website)

Comment: @AnnaLear no its not duplicate of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using(System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    MessageBox.Show(wc.DownloadString("http://thewebsite.com/thepage.html")); // Or whatever
}
```

Comment: woah this works, but the problem is that it returns the source of the site.

Comment: @user848682: And what exactly is it that you want...?

Comment: actually, I only need the what is inside of the given URL. I dont need the html formatting or whatever it is called.. is it possible? or perhaps I need to use regex to filter the string from wc.DownloadString? Thanks for the reply

Comment: @user848682: Sure, parse it with whatever you want. For serious data extraction, though, use an HTML library.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ANSWER. I finally made it work using Regex + ur wonderful code : )

Answer (score 1):

I need more clarification, unless I'm just being dense.

Are you wanting to capture the output of this URL from the command line?

If so, you could use

```
wget -q "http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Queens.java.html" -O captured_file.txt
```

Again, forgive me if I completely misunderstand the request...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
/// ---- ScreenScrape --------------------------------
///
/// <summary>
/// Input: URL like  "http://www.microsoft.com"
/// Return: HTML string of site
/// </summary>

static public String ScreenScrape(String URL)
{
    WebRequest TheRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    WebResponse TheResponse = TheRequest.GetResponse();

    StreamReader TheStreamReader = new StreamReader(TheResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

    String HTML = TheStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    return HTML;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I need the content not the string.. but thanks for the reply